# Can i use TextSplit with Find formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am making a table up that will sum all matches of a company found within a specific time period. I need to also exclude certain months if they are inserted into a cell as `mm/yy`. Excluding one month is fine but when i type `10/22, 11/22`, it will sum everthing. THe below code is what i am using with `U$4` being the end of a month minus the tracking period which is 90 days. Note that the Raw Data that it is reading from only goes to end of November.

```
=IF([@[Company Name]]="","",SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH([@[Company Name]],RawData[Description]))=TRUE,IF(RawData[Home]=XLOOKUP($D$1,HomeList[Home Code],HomeList[Home]),IF(RawData[Source]="Spend Money",IF(RawData[Date]<=U$4,IF(RawData[Date]>=U$4-[@[Tracking period (Days)]],1,0)))))))
```

With one date inserted which is correct:

```
                                                28/Feb  31/Mar  30/Apr  31/May  30/Jun  31/Jul  31/Aug  30/Sep 31/Oct   30/Nov  31/Dec  31/Jan

Exclude Company Name    Tracking period (Days)  Month 1 Month 2 Month 3 Month 4 Month 5 Month 6 Month 7 Month 8 Month 9 Month 10 Month 11 Month 12
11/22   CLH                       90               0        0      0       0       0      0        0       1       2       2       1       0
```

With multiple months inserted which is incorrect:

```
                                                28/Feb  31/Mar  30/Apr  31/May  30/Jun  31/Jul  31/Aug  30/Sep 31/Oct   30/Nov  31/Dec  31/Jan

Exclude    Company Name Tracking period (Days)  Month 1 Month 2 Month 3 Month 4 Month 5 Month 6 Month 7 Month 8 Month 9 Month 10 Month 11 Month 12
10/22,11/22   CLH                    90            0        0      0       0       0      0        0       2       3       8       6       5
```

Expected if multiple months as it has found one match for September so counts it

```
                                                     28/Feb 31/Mar  30/Apr  31/May  30/Jun  31/Jul  31/Aug  30/Sep 31/Oct   30/Nov  31/Dec  31/Jan

Exclude     Company Name    Tracking period (Days)  Month 1 Month 2 Month 3 Month 4 Month 5 Month 6 Month 7 Month 8 Month 9 Month 10 Month 11 Month 12
10/22,11/22   CLH                     90               0        0      0       0       0      0        0       1       1       1       0       0
```

Comment: I think you can. Put few sample data then desired output. Only formula doesn't make sense what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please post data as text. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to use `MATCH` with the `TEXTSPLIT` for it to work

```
=IF([@[Company Name]]="","",SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH([@[Company Name]],RawData[Description]))=TRUE,IF(RawData[Home]=XLOOKUP($D$1,HomeList[Home Code],HomeList[Home]),IF(RawData[Source]="Spend Money",IF(RawData[Date]<=S$4,IF(RawData[Date]>=S$4-[@[Tracking period (Days)]],IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(RawData[Find Date],TEXTSPLIT([@Exclude],","),)),0,1))))))))
```